# Search function using PHP and PDO not working

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to create a search function in PHP. I am using following functions:

In show.php:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="?controller=address&action=searchAll" method="post">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input class="form-control" id="terms" name="terms" type="text" placeholder="Search terms">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"> </span> Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This form sends a POST call to an controller: addressController.php

```
function searchAll(){
if (!empty($_POST['terms'])) {
        $terms=$_POST['terms'];
        $address=Address::searchByTerms($terms);
        $listaAddresses[]=$address;
        //var_dump($id);
        //die();
        require_once('Views/Address/show.php');
    } else {
        $listaAddresses=Address::all();

        require_once('Views/Address/show.php');
    }


}
```

And the controller should call the action searchByTerms to the model file Address.php and then open show.php again showing only the filtered items :

```
public static function searchByTerms($terms){
        $db=Db::getConnect();
        $select=$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM tb_direcciones   WHERE fn LIKE "%:fn%"');
        $select->bindValue('fn',$terms);
        $select->execute();

        $addressDb=$select->fetch();


        $address = new Address ($addressDb['id_address'],$addressDb['cia'], $addressDb['fn'], $addressDb['ln'], $addressDb['type'], $addressDb['phone'], $addressDb['fromto'], $addressDb['direccion'], $addressDb['latitud'], $addressDb['longitud']);
        //var_dump($address);
        //die();
        return $address;

    }
```

But something is wrong in my code then the error function is thrown.

Comment: Can you give the error output?

Comment: [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Answer (score 0):

> $select->bindValue(1, "%$terms%", PDO::PARAM_STR);

is right but you must declare `%$terms%` out side `bind Value`

```
$terms= "%".$terms."%";
$select->bindValue(1, $terms, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: Thank you for you time and effort, but I guess the problem is not on the query part of the code. It must be in some of the controller or model functions

Comment: Sorry To Ask but  `action="?controller=address&action=searchAll"` what suppose to do

Comment: this param should call the function searchAll from the controller

Comment: pls. bear with me suppose to call Controller page in same page show.php or in different

Comment: However if in same page or in different page USE $_GET to call controller=address&action=searchAll And then you can use $_POST

Answer (score 0):

I think your PDO::bindValue() function is wrong.

According th the PHP Documentation here:
http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindvalue.php, the bindValue function should take as the first argument the parameter name  in the form

> :name

Example:

```
bindValue (":name", $value, $data_type);
```

So maybe the code should be like:

```
$select=$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM tb_direcciones   WHERE fn LIKE "%:fn%"');

// here the right form
$select->bindValue(':fn', $terms, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Or if you want to use the index form with the question mark of the bindValue function, the solution could be on the form:

```
$select=$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM tb_direcciones   WHERE fn LIKE "%?%"');

// here the right form
$select->bindValue(1, $terms, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: Thank you for you time and effort, but I guess the problem is not on the query part of the code. It must be in some of the controller or model functions

Comment: there is no php error message, it is calling the error function inside the controller, that means that something on any of both functions (controller and model) is wrong